# reading wearable devices health data streams in C#

Tags: c#, health-monitoring

Beside *Microsoft Band* and its Microsoft-shipped nugets and VS templates, are there any open source C# libraries to access health data streams generated from wearable *devices*.

My requirement is (for fun) to get a wearable device that can connect either over internet and make Rest-based POST calls to a WCF running on my server, or to fetch the data from the device by connecting it to the Server physically (for instance USB) on regular basis such as every night/week/ .. etc.

I know my question is broad, but basically I am looking for developers who may already worked on such projects in C#, so I might be know more about what devices can be compatible with C#, or how others can interact with the most famous devices like Apple Watch, Samsung Band ... etc.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a software libraryare off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: this is sort of new question in SO, and maybe draw some attention to wearable devices and C# thats my question's goal